# Polygon boundaries in PostGIS spatial predicates

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a PostGIS enabled PostgreSQL database with 2 tables that contain polygon geometries called "developments" and "farm_portions".

A development is a collection of 1 or more farm portions.

I want to know which PostGIS function I must use that is similar to ST_Contains that will return TRUE if a row from "farm_portions" has a geometry that is inside the geometry of a row of "developments", including the boundaries of the polygons.

[image]

The picture above shows the development (black outline) that is formed by 6 farm portions. All the farm portions share a boundary with the development boundary, but the ST_Contains function doesn't return any TRUE values.

If I use the ST_Intersects function, it will return true for farm portions that are outside the development but share a boundary, so it's not the right function.

Which function should I use?

Comment: St-covers should do that I think

Comment: I try ST_Covers but it doesn't work

Comment: What expression are you using? Maybe your farms arent inside. Try difference farms with development to see if there are parts left that are outside

Comment: This is an issue of inaccuracy - for non-equal borders to align perfectly, vertex distribution needs to align perfectly; this is highly unlikely in a mathematically infinite vector space represented with floating point (im)precision.

Comment: @geozelot can you please elaborate?

 am trying the function with a large dataset and it works fine in some instances and doesn't work in others... I'm starting to think that the code is fine but there's something wrong with some geometries.

Is there a solution to the problem?

Comment: Buffer the development will a very small distance and st_covers will work

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PostGIS manual `st_covers`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Covers.html) should be the solution to your problem:

> Returns true if no point in Geometry/Geography B is outside Geometry/Geography A. Equivalently, tests if every point of geometry B is inside (i.e. intersects the interior or boundary of) geometry A.

Comment: `ST_Contains` should work for this as well.  The problem is likely that the geometries are not fully noded together, so the portion polygons aren't actually fully contained/covered.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, the reason that `ST_Contains` and `ST_Covers` are **not** giving the expected answer is that the `farm_portion` polygons probably have small areas lying outside the `developments` polygon, due to different noding.

Another technique is to test if a point inside a farm_portion polygon lies in a development polygon:

```
ST_Contains(developments.geom, ST_PointOnSurface(farm_portion.geom))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is imprecision in the geometries, calculate the area of intersection and then add a cutoff for the minimum area of overlap.

```
ST_Intersects(developments.geom, farm_portion.geom)
AND ST_Area(ST_Intersection(developments.geom, farm_portion.geom)) > your_cutoff
```